# Android BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray returns null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, bitmapfactory

I am trying to load an image from json data into an ImageView in android but BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray is always returning null.
On the server side i am reading a jpeg file from disk and loading it into a byte array which is a member of Result class. The result class object is then returned by the controller method then converted into json by JacksonHttpMessageConverter.

```
public class Result {

    //other members + getters and setters
    byte[] imageData;
}
```

on the android side i try to convert the byte array to bitmap

```
Result result = mapper.readValue(responseBody, Result.class);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result.getImageData(), 0,result.getImageData().length);
resultimage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

bmp is always null leading to an exception.
If i view the json data on firefox browser it seems ok and the size of the image data matches the one of the file on disk. BitmapFactory doesn't recognize the byte array as a valid image i don't understand why since i just read it from a file and send all the bytes to the android client.

Comment: You should post code of result.getImageData() and mapper.readValue() for more info.

Comment: Dump received byte array to a file on client side, examine the file if it is a valid image.

Comment: If the server encodes all to json then where are you decoding a byte array from json? You are not even talking about it. And encoding to json? An image? That will be base64 encoded in json text. You do all the steps in reverse? Follow S.D.'s advice as that will tell you a lot. Examine with wordpad.

Comment: Actually it was the Imageview pointer that was null. Had forgot to initialize it. just can't believe i couldn't see that. sorry for any inconvenience caused.